# What error do I have in my script that's preventing my buttons from inserting text before and after my image?

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Add Elements</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".test").click(function () {
          $("img").before["Before"];
        });
        $(".test2").click(function () {
          $("img").after["After"];
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Example:</h3>
    <p>
      Text will be inserted before and after the selected HTML element (img)
      upon clicking the respective buttons.
    </p>
    <img
      src="https://forums.homecomingservers.com/uploads/monthly_2020_10/2400px-Issue27-fullsize.png.b4bbd047f7804c86e1b10df2b90ac37c.png"
      alt="Issue 27"
      style="width: 500px"
    />
    <br />
    <button class="test">Insert Before</button>
    <button class="test2">Insert After</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the above code, I'm doing an example using jQuery to add elements to the image I have in my code. When the user clicks the "Insert Before" button and the "Insert After" button, text is supposed to be inserted before and after my image, respectively. However, upon clicking the buttons, nothing returns. What error do I have in my code?

Comment: `$("img").before["Before"];` looks like you're calling this incorrectly, try: `$("img").before("Before");`

Comment: Ah, thank you. Very small oversight on my part. That fixed it.